# Needing a git-svn workflow suggestion to keep personal files away from svn

Tags: git, workflow, git-svn

I am starting to read about git-svn now to use it with a project that use SVN.

I would like to have some files just for me (todo files, scratch code, etc), and I will like to keep track of them in the Git repository. Is it possible to have some files in the Git but not in the SVN repository?

I though about having a branch `master` that will be synchronized with the SVN repository and keep my work into another branch (`work`), but then I will need to merge/rebase `work` into `master` before pushing changes to SVN and remove these files and commits/log messages related to them... seems unpractical (and I don't know how to do it).

I am also thinking about adding a lot of comments into the code as I am understanding it, but most of them I should keep just for me.

Does anyone have a workflow suggestion to keep some files away from the SVN repository?

Or should I just forget this idea and have another git repository for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be afraid to branch and merge, this is extremely easy with Git. Just keep the local changes on a separate branch, let's call it `play`, and do the rest of your work either on `master` (which I assume is synchronized with Subversion trunk) or feature branches.

After pulling new changes from Subversion you could rebase `play` on top of `master` to get the latest code and resolve potential conflicts. If you change your mind and decide that some of `play` changes should be published, you can always cherry-pick individual commits on top of `master` and push them to Subversion.

Comment: Your answer is right, I was doing something similar in another situation (without git-svn).
However, in this case finally I did not use git-svn because of some other limitations (e.g. it was mandatory to set some propsets on new files on the svn server, and git-svn is not able to do it).

Answer (score 0):

Why do your todo files and so forth need to be in the same repository with the rest of the code?  Just make a new repository somewhere else on your machine.

Comment: Initially, it just seemed better to have them in the same repository. I've edited the question to make this clear.
But yes, it is totally possible (and practical) to just have another repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your own stuff peppered throughout your git repo, take a look at [`mine`](https://github.com/atstp/hey_git_thats_mine).

> Looks like it's sugar around the line `*_mine_*` in your global gitignore 
>   file, which lets you have a project structure like so:
>
> ```
> project-root/
>     tempBugList_mine_  # git will ignore this file
>     readme.md
>     _mine_/            # everything in this dir will be ignored by git
>         notes
>         promotion-ideas
>     lib/
>         fileone
>         filetwo
>     _mine_foodForThought    # ignored by git too!
> ```
>
> `mine` can `snapshot`, `clean`, and `restore` those `*_mine_*` files & dirs `git clean` and friends can't blow away your personal stuff.